# softlayer billing api to get a past invoice

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

wondering is there a softlayer rest api that i can use to get an invoice for a particular month from the past.

For instance, i want to pull the invoice for the month of April 2016. i looked at [Softlayer Billing Invoice](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice) service but in vain.

Also i do see a property called createDate on an invoice object but not sure if it can be of any help for the given scenario.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be possible using [Object Filters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters), in this case it's necessary to use a filter between dates, try the below example for it:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={"invoices":{"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["04/01/2016 00:00:00"]},{"name":"endDate","value":["04/30/2016 23:59:59"]}]}}}
    
Method: Get
```

It will display invoices between **04/01/2016 00:00:00** and **04/30/2016 23:59:59**

**References:**

- [SoftLayer_Account::getInvoices](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices)

---

> **Updated**

### How to get a single invoice for a specific month?

You need to get the information from **invoice with "typeCode": "RECURRING"**, in this case, you can use the following request:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getInvoices?objectFilter={"invoices":{"createDate":{"operation":"betweenDate","options":[{"name":"startDate","value":["06/01/2016 00:00:00"]},{"name":"endDate","value":["06/30/2016 23:59:59"]}]}, "typeCode":{"operation":"RECURRING"}}}

Method: Get
```

Comment: thanks Ruber for quick response. When i tried to get the invoice for our softlayer account for the month of April 2016, the service returned around 110 invoices (most of them are of type NEW). does softlayer provide one single bill for a particular month that has all the billing items? may be the monthly service bill that correponds to softlayer account's anniversary date?

Comment: Please see the **Updated** section in my answer

Comment: sorry to bother you Ruber. please bear with me here. am i correct in saying that for a given month there will be one and only invoice of type "RECURRING"? And wondering what about the "invoice items" that fall under the invoice of type "NEW" and "ONE_TIME_CHARGE'. i mean do they get added to invoice of type "RECURRING" automatically? Appreciate if you could share some doc on invoice,invoice items and billing items. Below link seems to be give only a brief overview [link](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice)

Comment: There should be only one **RECURRING per month** as you said. Regarding to **invoice items** do you refer to **items**? or do you wish to have the items that an invoice has?
In both cases the "NEW" and "ONE_TIME_CHARGE" should be added automatically to "RECURRING" invoice. If you have more than one "RECURRING" invoice, it would good to review the items that belongs to each one (Getting the "items" property for each one).

Comment: Unfortunately there is not another doc available for this, probably this: [View Invoice](https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/view-invoice), but I believe it displays similar information. Feel free to ask if you have any doubt or comment please